# Mac terminal nm command，get error！

Tags: shell

when I input **nm** command in terminal，get follow error. how to fix it? thanks!

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: a.out: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Let's start by ruling out the obvious: *is* there actually an `a.out`?

Comment: It's telling you exactly what the problem is - `a.out` doesn't exist. Show us the command you typed and the directory listing for where you ran it from.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy No

Comment: Well, then why would you expect it to work (if you don't give it a filename, and the default one doesn't exist)?

Comment: I input this command `nm -u libStaticLib.a `,just want to see symbol in static lib. but there is no output

Comment: `tiandeMac-mini:Debug-iphoneos mac$ nm -u libStaticLib.a `
`tiandeMac-mini:Debug-iphoneos mac$ nm -u `  
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/nm: a.out: No such file or directory.`

Comment: So, the valid question is why you got no output when you used it correctly, not why you get an error when you use it incorrectly. You should [edit] to ask that question, with a [mcve] letting other folks reproduce the problem (perhaps with a pointer to a publicly-available static library for which the problem occurs, or -- better -- with an accompanying short script that creates such a library).

Comment: Do you find  any  solution for this error